# How to convert a list of pandas dataframes into a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have a list of `pd.DataFrame` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df_list = [df, df]
```

**Question:**
How can I convert it to a 3D `np.array` with `shape` (2, 3, 5)?

I tried to do `np.array(df_lsit)`, but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 5
```

Comment: `np.stack(df_list)`?

Comment: Genius you are... :) Thanks! This works perfectly.

Comment: @Divakar add that comment as an answer and help OP close this one? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [map()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) and [df.to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html?highlight=to_numpy#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('abcde'))
df_list = [df, df]

np_array = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x.to_numpy(), df_list)))

# to make sure the shape of np_array is correct
np_array = np_array.reshape((x, y, z))
```

The column order in the Zth dimension will be the same as the column order in the pandas DataFrame. So, if you desire a certain order of the columns, you need to recorder the columns before running df.to_numpy().

Of course, you can recorder the columns in NumPy form, but reordering them in pandas DataFrame will be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your DataFrame to numpy array then convert it to 3D array.
Like this:

```
np.array([np.array(df), np.array(df)])
```